# Shared library g++ error segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn shared library (data structures) using c++; every time I run my program, it gives this error:

```
sachin@sachin-desktop:~$ cd /home/sachin/sDL
sachin@sachin-desktop:~/sDL$ g++ -fPIC -shared myclass.cc -o myclass.so
sachin@sachin-desktop:~/sDL$ g++ class_user.cc -ldl -o class_user
sachin@sachin-desktop:~/sDL$ ./class_user
0
Unable to load Sachin's library 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
sachin@sachin-desktop:~/sDL$
```

shared.h file

```
typedef struct node 
{
    struct node *prev;
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}NODE,*PNODE;


class SinglyCLL
{
    private :
    PNODE head;
    PNODE tail;
    public :
    SinglyCLL();
    ~SinglyCLL();
    virtual void InsertFirst(int);
    virtual void InsertLast(int);
    virtual void InsertAtPosition(int,int);
    virtual void DeleteFirst();
    virtual void DeleteLast();
    virtual void DeleteAtPosition(int);
    virtual int Count();
    virtual void Display();

};
```

myclass.cc file

```
#include"sharedfile.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

SinglyCLL::SinglyCLL()
{
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
}

void SinglyCLL::InsertFirst(int ino)
{
    PNODE temp=head;
    PNODE newN=NULL;

    newN=new NODE;
    newN->next=NULL;
    newN->data=ino;
    newN->prev=NULL;

    if((head==NULL)&&(tail==NULL))
    {
        head=newN;
        tail=newN;
        tail->next=head;
        head->prev=tail;
    }

    newN->next=head;
    head->prev=newN;
    head=newN;
    tail->next=head;
    head->prev=tail;

}

void SinglyCLL::Display()
{
    PNODE temp=head;

    if((head==NULL)&&(tail==NULL))
    {
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<endl;
        temp=temp->next;

    }while(tail->next!=temp);
}

SinglyCLL::~SinglyCLL()
{
    delete head;
    delete tail;
}

extern "C"
{
    SinglyCLL *create()
    {
        return new SinglyCLL;
    }
    void destroy (SinglyCLL* p)
    {
        delete p;
    }
}
```

class_user.cc file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "sharedfile.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void *p=NULL;
    SinglyCLL *ptr=NULL;
    SinglyCLL* (*fp1)()=NULL;
    void (*fp2)(SinglyCLL*)=NULL;

    p=dlopen("/home/sachin/sDL/myclass.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!p)
    {
        cout<<p<<endl;
        printf("Unable to load Sachin's library \n");
    }

    fp1=(SinglyCLL*(*)())dlsym(p,"create");
    fp2=(void(*)(SinglyCLL*))dlsym(p,"destroy");

    ptr=fp1();

    ptr->InsertFirst(10);
    /*ptr->InsertAtPosition(70,1);
    ptr->InsertAtPosition(80,2);*/
    ptr->Display();

    fp2(ptr);
    dlclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I run this program, a segmentation fault occurs. I am using singly circular list to create a linked-list to store data. I have gone through the code and failed to locate the error. I am unable to understand why it's not running as I tried to run singly linked-list with shared library which is running fine without any error. I have checked the permissions to access the files, which is fine.

As I am learning to create data structures in a shared library just for educational purposes, there might be chances of improvement or something to change in this code outside the part which causing the problem.

Comment: ldd <binary name> will show you which .so will be loaded when you run that binary. If there is a gap for your so, it means the loader does not find it in runtime. You have to set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. And don't put the problem of .so and logic together. See if you can call a simple function from the .so before trying out linked lists.

Comment: if `head` and `tail` points to the same thing, you're doing a double `delete`.

Comment: Call `dlerror` to get an error message.

Comment: You detect that a library isn't loaded, print an error message, then continue to use the non-existent library like there's no tomorrow. What do you want to happen if not a crash?

Comment: Always compile with `g++ -Wall -g` instead of your use of just `g++`. Then use the `gdb` debugger

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After tinkering with your code, I'm changing my answer!

@Zsigmond is correct in pointing out that you need to define the methods in the header file; however, that doesn't completely solve the problem.

I compiled your source and recreated the problem you saw (the segmentation fault on load). I resolved that by adding implementations for the other functions in shared.h

After that, I got this error:

`*** Error in ./class_user: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000002478660 ***`

I was able to narrow this down to the `fp2(ptr)` line; commenting this line out removed the error.

Updated code is below.

Updated shared.h:

```
// Header Guard (prevents duplicate symbols)
#ifndef __SHARED_H
#define __SHARED_H

// C++ syntax for a struct doesn't need typedef
struct node
{
    node* prev;
    int data;
    node* next;
};


class SinglyCLL
{
private :
    node* head;
    node* tail;
public :
    SinglyCLL();
    ~SinglyCLL();
    virtual void InsertFirst(int);
    virtual void InsertLast(int);
    virtual void InsertAtPosition(int,int);
    virtual void DeleteFirst();
    virtual void DeleteLast();
    virtual void DeleteAtPosition(int);
    virtual int Count();
    virtual void Display();

};

#endif // __SHARED_H
```

Updated myclass.cc:

```
#include"shared.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

SinglyCLL::SinglyCLL()
{
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
}

void SinglyCLL::InsertFirst(int ino)
{
    node* temp=head;
    node* newN=NULL;

    newN=new node;
    newN->next=NULL;
    newN->data=ino;
    newN->prev=NULL;

    if((head==NULL)&&(tail==NULL))
    {
        head=newN;
        tail=newN;
        tail->next=head;
        head->prev=tail;
    }

    newN->next=head;
    head->prev=newN;
    head=newN;
    tail->next=head;
    head->prev=tail;

}

void SinglyCLL::Display()
{
    node* temp=head;

    if((head==NULL)&&(tail==NULL))
    {
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<endl;
        temp=temp->next;

    }while(tail->next!=temp);
}

SinglyCLL::~SinglyCLL()
{
    delete head;
    delete tail;
}

extern "C"
{
    SinglyCLL *create()
    {
        return new SinglyCLL;
    }
    void destroy (SinglyCLL* p)
    {
        delete p;
    }
}

// Empty implementations for the other functions
void SinglyCLL::InsertLast(int)
{

}

void SinglyCLL::InsertAtPosition(int,int)
{

}

void SinglyCLL::DeleteFirst()
{

}

void SinglyCLL::DeleteLast()
{

}

void SinglyCLL::DeleteAtPosition(int)
{

}

int SinglyCLL::Count()
{

}
```

Updated class_user.cc:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "shared.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void *p=NULL;
    SinglyCLL *ptr=NULL;
    SinglyCLL* (*fp1)()=NULL;
    void (*fp2)(SinglyCLL*)=NULL;

    p=dlopen("/home/mike/Projects/C++/myclass.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!p)
    {
        cout<<p<<endl;
        cout << "Unable to load Sachin's library" << endl;
    }

    fp1=(SinglyCLL*(*)())dlsym(p,"create");
    fp2=(void(*)(SinglyCLL*))dlsym(p,"destroy");

    ptr=fp1();

    ptr->InsertFirst(10);
    ptr->InsertAtPosition(70,1);
    ptr->InsertAtPosition(80,2);
    ptr->Display();

    // Un-comment next line to force the 'double free' error.
    //fp2(ptr);
    dlclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my program is giving me error after i call dlerror                                 "/home/sachin/sDL/myclass1.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9SinglyCLL10InsertLastEi
"                                                                                                                     Can anyone help me to me how to solve it ?

Comment: `myclass1.so` has never been mentioned before. Please be more precise. Demangling the name you get this message: `/home/sachin/sDL/myclass1.so: undefined symbol: SinglyCLL::InsertLast(int)`

Comment: I would say you have to implement _every_ virtual methods, because their addresses will be stored in VMT

Answer (score 0):

Edited on Mike P's suggestion:

You not only have to implement *every* virtual method you declare in the header; you have to fix your destructor too. It would be something like this:

```
SinglyCLL::~SinglyCLL()
{
    node *q, *next;

    if (head) {
        next= head->next;
        delete head;

        while ((q= next) != head) {
            next=  q->next;
            delete q;
        }
    }
    head= tail= NULL;
}
```

Note: actually, as it is a circular list, 'tail' pointer could be removed.

Comment: You are right that he didn't write the destructor, but only adding the destructor won't solve the segmentation fault.

Comment: I've tested since, fixing the destructor and implementing _every_ method declared in the header does fix the segmentation fault. Feel free to test it.

Comment: But only adding the destructor won't solve the problem. Your answer only mentions the destructor, not the other methods.